# How do I set the Post field after manipulation

Tags: plugin-development, usermodel

I'm trying to write a simple plugin that will intercept registration form's data, manipulate it and move it forward. What I'm struggling with is how to set the Post content of a field after the manipulation.

I'm trying to achieve something like that, how do I set the Post field after manipulation, setRawPostContent doesn't seem to work here.

```
 craft()->on('users.onBeforeSaveUser', function(Event $event) {

        if(craft()->request->isSiteRequest())
        {
            $companyId = craft()->request->getPost('email');
            $event->params['user']->setRawPostContent('fields[companyId]', $companyId);
        }

    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're just looking to update a custom field on the user, something like this should do it:

```
craft()->on('users.onBeforeSaveUser', function(Event $event) {

    if(craft()->request->isSiteRequest())
    {
        $companyId = craft()->request->getPost('email');
        $event->params['user']->getContent()->companyId = $companyId;
    }

});
```

Comment: Thank's Brad, that does work indeed.